# a parallel to serial transmitter in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

the code is for a parallel to serial transmitter that have reset ,go clk and sout

here is the code but it give me errors

> Improper array length (1). Expected length is 11.
>
> Error: COMP96_0083: proj22.vhd : (28, 9): The type of a choice expression does not match the case expression.
>
> Error: COMP96_0301: proj22.vhd : (26, 3): The choice 'others' must be present when all alternatives are not covered.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
entity trans is
    port(reset ,go :in std_logic;
    clk :in std_logic_vector(11 downto 1);
    pin:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);                       
    sout:out std_logic_vector(11 downto 1));
    
end entity trans ;

architecture transmitter  of trans is

signal clk_counter:std_logic_vector(11 downto 1);
--signal parity:std_logic;

begin
process(reset,go)

begin 
    --sout(10)<= parity;
    clk_counter <= clk;
    if (reset ='1' ) then 
        sout <=(others=>'1');
    if(reset ='0' and go ='1') then
        
        case clk_counter is
            when "1" =>   sout(1)<= '0' ;
            when "2" =>   sout(2)<= pin(0);
            when "3" =>   sout(3)<= pin(1);
            when "4" =>   sout(4)<= pin(2);
            when "5" =>   sout(5)<= pin(3);
            when "6" =>   sout(6)<= pin(4);
            when "7" =>   sout(7)<= pin(5);
            when "8" =>   sout(8)<= pin(6);
            when "9" =>   sout(9)<= pin(7);
            when "10" =>  sout(10) <= pin(0) xor pin(1) xor pin(2) xor pin(3) xor pin(4) xor pin(5) xor pin(6) xor pin(7);
            when "11"=>   sout(11)<= '1';
    
        end case;   
    end if ;
    end if;
end process;
end architecture transmitter;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're more likely to get a useful answer if you follow the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, what is happening, what were you expecting to happen? Secondly, provide something executable so that someone else can easily see what you're seeing. Finally, just supply the minimum code required to reproduce the problem. These last two are called an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MatthewTaylor thanks for fixing this mess.

Answer (score 3):

> Improper array length (1). Expected length is 11.
>
> Error: COMP96_0083: proj22.vhd : (28, 9): The type of a choice expression does not match the case expression.

VHDL is a *strongly typed* language. `clk_counter` is 12 bits wide. It must be compared with something at is (a) a compatible *literal* (a hard-coded value) and (b) has the same width. `"1"` is (a) a string and (b) the wrong width. You must use binary strings for a `std_logic_vector` and the width must match, eg:

```
when "00000000001" =>   sout(1)<= '0' ;
when "00000000010" =>   sout(1)<= sout(2)<= pin(0);
```

> Error: COMP96_0301: proj22.vhd : (26, 3): The choice 'others' must be present when all alternatives are not covered.

In VHDL `case` statements must be complete - there must be no choices missing. Usually, there will be some choices not covered by the banches; these can be covered by adding an "others" branch. (To be frank, the error message pretty much tells you this, which might also explain all your downvotes), eg:

```
when others =>   sout= (others => 'X') ;
```